# Visitor Attraction questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask a question relating to tourist-targetted visitor attractions. I have a very particular kind of attraction in mind and a specific geographical region, but, despite searching and being reasonably confident that such an attraction probably exists, cannot find one which obviously fits. I would not be seeking "the best", nor reviews or opinions of quality. I may just be lacking some tricks in how to search for it.

Is this on-topic for this site? The "Asking a question" FAQs I find seem to place it in a no-man's land between the "IS" and "IS NOT" lists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it ought to be on-topic. There are a few questions like that already, some of them quite successful like [Are there any analogs of the Malbork castle in Poland or Germany?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/465/are-there-any-analogs-of-the-malbork-castle-in-poland-or-germany), [Scenic restaurant overlooking Washington DC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30391/scenic-restaurant-overlooking-washington-dc), [Vantage point in Austin, Texas for photos?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/vantage-point-in-austin-texas-for-photos) or [What is the indoor climbing wall closest to the centre of Sydney?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/what-is-the-indoor-climbing-wall-closest-to-the-centre-of-sydney). If the criteria are specific enough that finding a match is not trivial and providing an exhaustive list is possible, I don't see why it would not be a good match for this site's format.

But, realistically, you need to be careful with the formulation and ideally explain what research you have done on your own as some users do react negatively to these sort of questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that asking for how to find something travel related is generally fine. We have quite a few questions like that already. It's generally better to have an answer that explains how to do something general, rather than have 50 specific questions for each tiny permutation

Asking others to find things for you needs care. If it's likely to produce more than 3 or 4 results, take care, and more than about 6 or 7 and it's likely to be a "list-based" question and closed. There's also issues with keeping the answers up-to-date as things change. Something likely to produce 0, 1 or 2 places is more often OK.

Another thing to do is look for similar questions, to get an idea, and possibly also mention in the question. "I have a similar question to [x], but for [specific difference]" tends to go down better than one which seems not to be aware of our rules. However, we did allow a wider range of things in the early days of the site's beta, so take care citing very very old questions

Answer (score -4):

This is indeed not the intended use of this website, the question does not fit any of the things you are supposed to ask for. And the question risks falling in all of the categories not to ask: as subjective, overly broad, list-style, ... in the end, because it is not possible to judge the relative quality of the different answers.

However, based on the questions we have and the attitude of the community, I believe this can be OK to ask for a specific facility in a specific region. The trick is to ask something that is neither in a too broad area nor too localized, neither including too many types of facilities nor too few, and it is ideally possible to objectively weigh the multiple answers received.

So I would suggest two options. The first is you expect that your attraction may exist but you searched and failed to find it. You can ask, and if other people judge you didn't try or it is too broad, it'll be closed.

The second option is to ask how to find it. Typically one does not ask if there is a specific type of hotel in some city, but if there is a directory or a search engine for this.

Comment: If the community is OK with it, by whom is not intended?

Comment: I think the intentions are written principles, the community applies them with a "human" eye.